# How to work with one table view with 2 sections and multiple cell identifiers?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, charts

I created a small app which shows 2 charts (line and pie chart) using Charts (see [Figure_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTG4c.png)) and now I would like to do the same 2 charts using a tableView controller, with 2 sections and each section would have the line and the pie chart respectively (so, basically: 2 sections with one chart each inside a cell/row in the section).

Until this point, I was able to create the 2 sections with one row with a view chart each (see [Figure_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j6eP.png)). But now that I try to manipulate the code to add the data on each row of each section, I just get errors and the app crashes.

I'm kind of new in Swift 4 so I'm kind of stuck.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class OtherChartsTableViewController: UITableViewController{

//MARK: - Variables and Constants
let titleOfSectionsArray = [" Line Chart", " Pie Chart"]
let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
let unitsSold = [20.3, 4.9, 6.4, 3.8, 12.2, 16.1, 11.7, 17.2, 9.0, 7.6, 25.3, 10.5]
var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []


//MARK: - Outlets, actions and views
@IBOutlet weak var lineChartView: LineChartView!
@IBOutlet weak var pieChartView: PieChartView!
@IBOutlet var otherChartsTableView: UITableView!

//MARK: - viewDidLoad()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

//MARK: - TableView delegates and datasources
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return titleOfSectionsArray.count

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 1

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let view = UIView()

    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = titleOfSectionsArray[section]
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 30)
    view.addSubview(label)

    print("Section tapped: \(section)")

    return view

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    print("Row tapped: \(indexPath.row)")

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0{

        //This line of code helped me to "detect" the reuse identifier for the cell in the Main.storyboard at the attributes inspector.
        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "IdLineChartCell")

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "IdLineChartCell", for: indexPath)
        //cell.selectionStyle = .none
        print("LineChartCell tapped")

        return cell

    } else {

        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "IdPieChartCell")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "IdPieChartCell", for: indexPath)
        //cell.selectionStyle = .none
        print("PieChartCell tapped")

        return cell

    }

}

}
```

I tried to add the view charts but I don't know if they appear in the row of each section, all I tried to code just fails, for instance, I tried to add 2 "no data texts" (as a simple step) in the viewDidLoad method for each chart (see [Figure_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPhXW.png)) and fails (figure 3 is from the other charts app that is not using a table view).

```
//MARK: - viewDidLoad()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pieChartView.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the pie chart"
    lineChartView.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the line chart"

}
```

I tried to use "if else" statements but I don't know how to make it look for each section to give the correct cell identifiers on each row of each section.

I know that the "if else" statement used in the cellForRowAt indexPath: method is completely wrong, but that depicts more or less what I want to do in order to show the charts.

The log of the crash when I use the pieChartView.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the pie chart" in viewDidLoad method is this:

> ```
> 2019-02-18 16:48:44.572821+0100 SamiChartTableViewStyle[25727:712814] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform.
> Other Charts
> otherChartsObject: <SamiChartTableViewStyle.OtherChartsTableViewController: 0x7fcb2242fbc0>
> 2019-02-18 16:48:45.696538+0100 SamiChartTableViewStyle[25727:712814] Unknown class _TtC23SamiChartTableViewStyle13LineChartCell in Interface Builder file.
> 2019-02-18 16:48:45.696820+0100 SamiChartTableViewStyle[25727:712814] Unknown class _TtC23SamiChartTableViewStyle13LineChartCell in Interface Builder file.
> 2019-02-18 16:48:45.697602+0100 SamiChartTableViewStyle[25727:712814] Unknown class _TtC23SamiChartTableViewStyle12PieChartCell in Interface Builder file.
> 2019-02-18 16:48:45.697772+0100 SamiChartTableViewStyle[25727:712814] Unknown class El in Interface Builder file.
> 2019-02-18 16:48:45.697895+0100 SamiChartTableViewStyle[25727:712814] Unknown class _TtC23SamiChartTableViewStyle12PieChartCell in Interface Builder file.
> (lldb)
> ```

Thanks in advance for your time and patience.

Comment: Please provide the log of the crash. You also need to use indexPath.section in if/else statement, but it can't be the reason of the crash, just logic mistake.

Comment: Hello Alexander. I will take a look to the indexPath.section recommendation that you suggest. Thanks.

Comment: **Never** register cells in `cellForRowAt` again and again. If you are using prototype cells you **must not** register cells at all. On the other hand if you are using extra xibs or creating the cells programmatically register the cells **once** in `viewDidLoad`. The error says that the custom classes are not assigned to the cells in Interface Builder.

Comment: Remove Register cell from cellForRow and add it into `viewDidLoad()` also all set just you need to set chart data for your line & pie charts.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. If any of you could please share an example similar to my case I'd appreciate it a lot, I'm kind of new and I'm still struggling to properly execute the advices that you guys give me. Thanks in advance.